# Android: Stop Back Button From Exiting LockTask / Kiosk Mode

Tags: java, android, kiosk-mode, device-admin

I want to implement a `KioskMode`, I'm targeting only `Android L`, since this is a very specific App.

I already went through the process of setting my App as DeviceAdmin, and
`DevicePolicyManager.isLockTaskPermitted(this.getPackageName())` already returns `true`.

I then start a `LockTask` via `startLockTask()`.

Everything is fine, but when I hold down the `backbutton`, the app still exits the kiosk mode.

I have overridden `onKeyPress` to show a custom Dialog for unlocking the app, but this does not hinder android to automatically exit my lock task if the user holds down back.

I don't really know what to do at the moment and would be thankful for every input.

I now have overridden

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        BackDownButtonPressed = true;
        if(VolDownPressed)
            showTaskLockDialog();
        return true;
    }
    else if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
    {
        VolDownPressed = true;
        if(BackDownButtonPressed)
            showTaskLockDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return  super.onKeyDown(KeyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        BackDownButtonPressed = false;
        return true;
    }
    else if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
    {
        VolDownPressed = false;
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(KeyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    return;
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigateUp() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent (KeyEvent event)
{
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //do something or nothing in your case
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

For the record, I am using a Samsung SM-T700 Tablet with Cyanogenmod CM12.1

Comment: Have you overriden onBackPressed() ?

Comment: Yes, I did, doesnt change the problem sadly

Comment: are you able to open up dialog on backbutton click ?

Comment: Try removing all the key method overrides except `onBackPressed()`.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede this doesnt work either, sadly

Comment: Have you found a solution by now? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: @Huby and timschoen - I've submitted a bug report. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67841010#comment1 Could you "star" it please?

Comment: I'm facing this problem in xiaomi devices as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close this topic..

I couldn't figure out a perfect solution to this day. My current workaround is receiving an event if the user leaves the kiosk mode and just entering the kiosk mode again.

Sadly this leaves the user with 2 toasts saying "screen unpinned" and "screen pinned", which is unfortunate. But this satisfies my current needs.

Comment: how can u get an event when user leaves the kiosk mode ? I am currently facing issue if user long pressed back button app exits from kiosk mode. Any workaround to avoid it.

Comment: @timschoen can you please elaborate how you achieved this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to override [onKeyLongPress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyLongPress(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent))

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //do something or nothing in your case
        return true
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: already tried that. The event seems to propagate even if i return true.

I now have overriden a few methods, see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32909074/revisions

Comment: can you add the actual overrides that you have written to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's helpful at all, but I wrote a blog about setting Kiosk Mode here:
http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-kiosk-mode-without-root/

And also wrote sample code for it here: 
https://github.com/sureshjoshi/android-kiosk-example

Not sure if you see any major differences between your code and mine, but I just tried to do a long press on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 running Android 5.0, and it won't exit the app.

Could it be something with rooting with Cyanogen?

If you don't have this in your code, perhaps add it in and check out if you see any problems:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Remove title bar and notification bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        ComponentName deviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
        mDpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        if (!mDpm.isAdminActive(deviceAdmin)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_device_admin), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (mDpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName())) {
            mDpm.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, new String[]{getPackageName()});
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_device_owner), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
}
```

and

```
protected void enableKioskMode(boolean enabled) {
        try {
            if (enabled) {
                if (mDpm.isLockTaskPermitted(this.getPackageName())) {
                    startLockTask();
                    mIsKioskEnabled = true;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.kiosk_not_permitted), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                stopLockTask();
                mIsKioskEnabled = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: Log and handle appropriately
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem: [How to stop "holding the back button" from escaping "Lock Task mode" on Android 6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771951/how-to-stop-holding-the-back-button-from-escaping-lock-task-mode-on-android)

The issue only occurs on my Android 7 tablet.

Running the app on my Android 6 tablet fixed the problem.

Could you add some code to illustrate your current work-around?