# How to stop "holding the back button" from escaping "Lock Task mode" on Android 7+

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, cosu

I'm attempting to use "Lock Task mode", as described on https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html

My goal is to have a single app running in a "kiosk mode", so that the user cannot leave the app.

I'm using Google's "Test DPC" app from Google Play as the DPC, which I have made the owner of the device via: `adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.afwsamples.testdpc/.DeviceAdminReceiver`.

It all works really well at keeping a trivial app (which calls `startLockTask()`) in kiosk mode.  (I have added this trivial app to Test DPCs list of apps which are allowed to use "Lock Task mode".)

The problem is that if a user holds the back button, they escape "Lock Task mode" while displaying a confusing toast of "App is pinned: unpinning is not allowed on this device".

Is there a way of stopping this escape mechanism?

---

Update: The problem occurs on an Asus P00A with Android 7, but does *not* occur on an Android P00C with Android 6.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue if the user clicks the home button (that can destroy the previous activity), next back button

A trick is to desactivate the back button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing
}
```

Comment: It only happens when a user "holds" the back button for a while, which does not cause `onBackPressed()` to be called.  It's starting to look like it's an ASUS-specific "feature" rather than an Android issue.

Comment: Also happens on Samsung A6 tablet. I believe it is Android 7.0+ specific not device. Above response does not resolve issue.